# Export a single column from datagridview to txt file using openfiledialog

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, export, text-files, datagridviewcolumn

I made a proxy checker in VB.NET. The good proxies are in a DataGridView like:

IP:
  Country :
  City :
  Region :

[image]

When it done, I want to export ONLY the IP's column to a text file using Openfiledialog.
I don't want the other columns like country or city.

Comment: What have you tried already? Seems simple. You use a `SaveFileDialog` to prompt the user to specify where to save the file. To actually save the file you could use `System.IO.File.WriteAllText()`

Comment: To create the text to write you simply need to loop through each row in the dgv and save to a variable.

Comment: With a `ForEach` loop on the `Rows` collection, get each Row cell at Column(0) if not null: `[Row].Cell(0).Value?.ToString()` would do. You probably mean a `SaveFileDialog`. So, `Using sfd As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog() sfd.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt"(...) If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then '(... Loop the Rows collection, add the Values to a List(Of string) ...) File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, [YourList].ToArray()) End If End Using`. Btw, being French is not an excuse for any bad English: you still think you're entitled to the Throne of England, right? :)

Comment: @Jimi it's ok for the SFD (http://prntscr.com/nhqa8c) But i don't understand how to make a for each loop on the row ?

Comment: Note the `Using` statement when declaring the `SaveFileDialog`: you need to dispose of that object. `If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then Dim myIps As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)() For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows Dim cellValue = row.Cells(0).Value?.ToString() If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cellValue) Then myIps.Add(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString()) End If Next File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, myIps.ToArray()) End If`.

Comment: @Jimi yeeeeeeeeeeah thank you verry much ! I understand better now with your explanations !

Comment: @Jimi Congratulations on 10,000 +!